# SQL Error - missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table, double-precision

Whats wrong with this query : I am getting following error

> SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

it says error at 4th row. Please advise

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
ID INT        NOT NULL,
ord_date    DATE, 
AMOUNT     double,
CUSTOMER_ID INT references CUSTOMERS(ID),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: shouldn't your `double` be a `number(10, 2)` or something similar depending on what you need?

Comment: @NicolásCarlo - I just tried double .but it seems it won't work in oracle 11g.  As per your suggestion I tried number .. it worked executed fine. Thanks for info.

Comment: No problem but @NoDisplayName 's answer is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes .. I appreciate your broad mind @NicolásCarlo. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 7):

You missed to add `precision` in `double` datatype

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(
   ID INT        NOT NULL,
   ord_date    DATE, 
   AMOUNT     double precision,
   CUSTOMER_ID INT references CUSTOMERS(ID),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cba8dd)**

For more info [***check here***](http://psoug.org/reference/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BIGINT` or `DECIMAL` type for double type.